# Azure Datafactory process and filter files to process

Tags: csv, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline that processes some files, and in some cases "groups" of files. Meaning the files should be processed together and are correlated with a timestamp.

Ex.

- **Timestamp**#Customer.csv
- **Timestamp**#Customer_Offices.csv
- **Timestamp_1**#Customer.csv
- **Timestamp_1**#Customer_Offices.csv

...

I have a table  with all the scopes, and files with respective filemask. I have populated a variable in the beginning of the pipeline based on a parameter

[image: pipeline]

The Get files activity goes to a sFTP location and grab files from a folder. Then I only want to process the "*Customer.csv" and "*.Customer_Offices.csv" files. This is because the folder location has more file types or scopes to be processed by other pipelines. If I don't filter, the next activities end up by processing metadata of files that are not supposed to. In terms of efficiency and performance s bad, and is even causing some issues with files being left behind.

[image: FilterSettings]

I've tried something like

@variables('FilesToSearch').contains(@endswith(item().name, 'do I need this 2nd parm in arrays ?'))

but no luck... :(

Any help will be highly appreciated,

Best regards,
Manuel

Answer (score 0):

`contains` function can direct for a string to find a substring, so you can try something like this expression `@contains(item().name,'Customer')`
and no need to create a variable.
[image]

Or use `endsWith` function and use this expression:

```
@or(endswith(item().name,'Customer.csv'),endswith(item().name,'Customer_Offices.csv'))
```

Comment: Thanks @Steve Zhao, this is what I need but I wanted a bit more dynamics. Instead of hard-coding the file mask(s) to search, the variable (of type array), would contain that list to filter. Is that possible? Regards,

Comment: Is the value of your variable ["Customer.csv","Customer_Offices.csv"]?

Comment: This is what I get from the var output. It has not the exact format but close. <code>{
    "name": "FilesToSearch",
    "value": [
        [
            {
                "FileMask": "Customers.csv"
            },
            {
                "FileMask": "Contacts.csv"
            },
            {
                "FileMask": "Sites.csv"
            }
        ]
    ]
}</code>

Comment: This is impossible to use an expression to achieve your requirement.